# Implementing delegate and events throws ambiguity error

Tags: c#, asp.net, events, c#-4.0, delegates

I have a link button added in custom control lnkprev. Now I have created a delegate and a event. I want to call it on lnkprev button's click. I am doing so in order to prevent closing of a section of page in which custom control is called.

```
    public delegate void PagePrevHandler();
    public event PagePrevHandler PagePrev;

    protected void lnkprev_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        PagePrev();
    }

    public void PagePrev()
    {
        List<ListItem> pages = new List<ListItem>();
        int pageCount = TotalPages;
        int lastnumber = FirstNumber - 10;
        int nexttennumber = lastnumber + 10;

        if (lastnumber >= 0)
        {
            if (lastnumber == 0)
            {
                lastnumber = 1;
                nexttennumber = 11;
            }
            for (int i = lastnumber; i <= pageCount; i++)
            {
                if (i < nexttennumber && i > 0)
                {
                    pages.Add(new ListItem(i.ToString(), i.ToString(), i != PageIndex));
                }
            }
            FirstNumber = lastnumber;
            LastNumber = nexttennumber;
            rptPager.DataSource = pages;
            rptPager.DataBind();
        }
    }
```

Now the issues is that it throws error saying ambiguity issues.
"already contains a definition for 'PagePrev'"

Actually I am not getting the concept of delegates and events from online sources. I have never implemented them.

Please help me !!!

Comment: what are you using event for? lnkprev_Click itself is a delegate

Comment: Just delete the `public event PagePrevHandler PagePrev;` and you get working (compiling) code. When you need a PagePrev event, ask a much more focused question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A delegate defines a function signature. It can be used as is to define the type of a callback function:

```
public class MyPageClass
{
    public delegate void FirstPageCallback(string pageTitle);

    // Method with a callback function
    public void SomePageProcessing(FirstPageCallback fpcb, int pageNumber)
    {
        // Do some stuff
        ...

        // Call the function defined in another class
        fpcb("This is a title");
    }
}
```

A function with the appropriate signature can then be declared in another class and passed to the method of a MyPageClass object:

```
public class MyClientClass
{
    private MyPageClass p = new MyPageClass();

    private void ProcessPages()
    {
        // Pass DoFirstPageStuff as callback function
        p.SomePageProcessing(DoFirstPageStuff, 7); 
    }    

    // This method has the signature specified by the FirstPageCallback delegate
    // It will be called inside p.SomePageProcessing
    private void DoFirstPageStuff(string title)
    {
        // Do something with the page title
        ...
    }
}
```

---

The `EventHandler` delegate is often used to declare events. You could use your own delegate but it is probably not necessary.

```
public class MyPageClass
{
    public event EventHandler FirstPageLoaded;

    public void MorePageProcessing(int pageNumber)
    {
        // Do some stuff
        ...

        // Call all the registered event handlers
        if (FirstPageLoaded != null)
        {
            FirstPageLoaded(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    }
}
```

A class that contains an instance of MyPageClass can register an event handler:

```
public class MyClientClass
{
    private MyPageClass p = new MyPageClass();

    private void ProcessMorePages()
    {
        // Register ProcessLoadedPage as event handler
        p.FirstPageLoaded += ProcessLoadedPage; 
    }    

    // This method has the same signature as the EventHandler delegate
    // It will be called inside p.MorePageProcessing
    private void ProcessLoadedPage(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

---

The `EventHandler` delegate has an `EventArgs` parameter, which does not contain any data. If your event handler needs additional data, you can derive a class from `EventArgs`:

```
public class FirstPageEventArgs: EventArgs
{
    public int PageNumber;
    public string Title;

    public FirstPageEventArgs(int pageNumber, string title)
    {
        PageNumber = pageNumber;
        Title = title;
    }
}
```

and include it in the event declaration with the generic version of `EventHandler`:

```
public event EventHandler<FirstPageEventArgs> FirstPageLoaded;
```

The event handlers would be triggered this way:

```
    if (FirstPageLoaded != null)
    {
        FirstPageLoaded(this, new FirstPageEventArgs(currentPageNumber, "My title"));
    }
```

and defined with the appropriate parameters:

```
private void ProcessLoadedPage(object sender, FirstPageEventArgs e)
{
    // Use the values of the derived EventArgs argument
    int pageNumber = e.PageNumber;
    string title = e.Title;
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have two elements with "PagePrev" name - event and method. What should be called, when you wrote:

```
PagePrev();
```

? I think, you should rename method or event and then everythink should work fine

Comment: how to write defination for the delegate PagePrev so that the functionality written in the above PagePrev method is called on lnkprev button's click

Comment: I am actually trying to find out how to give functionality to the delegate PagePrev